# Fetch bulk records from cassandra database and process in java threads with optimal performance

Tags: java, multithreading, cassandra, parallel-processing, java-8

I have cassandra tables with below definition

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PRODUCT_INV (
  Product_Code TEXT,
  Storecode TEXT,
  StoreType TEXT,
  ProductInfo TEXT,
  INVENTORY DECIMAL,
  PRIMARY KEY ((Product_Code, Storecode, StoreType)));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PRODUCT_BY_STORE (
  Storecode TEXT,
  StoreType TEXT,
  Product_Code SET<TEXT>,
  PRIMARY KEY ((Storecode, StoreType)));
```

PRODUCT_INV Table

```
Product_Code    Storecode   StoreType   ProductInfo  INVENTORY
    12             601       Retail        ABC         100
    12             601       Supermart     ABC         50
    13             601       Retail        DEF         10
    14             701       Retail        QWE         200 
    13             601       Supermart     ZXC         150
```

PRODUCT_BY_STORE Table

```
Storecode   StoreType   Product_Code
601          Retail        12,13
601          Supermart     12,13 
701          Retail        14
```

Now i want get the records from PRODUCT_INV for each and every product based on Product_Code,StoreType and Storecode and do some business operation.I can get the list of Product_Code for each storecode and storetype and then query PRODUCT_INV for each storecode,storecode and productcode.
My problem is that PRODUCT_BY_STORE table can contain upto 12000 rows. For each row in PRODUCT_BY_STORE, there can be upto 5000 product_code.In the worst case scenario, there will be 12000 * 5000 database calls and records to process by java application.

How can i achieve this using threads by keeping the optimal performance ? Is it a good idea to use Java 8 parallelstream ?

Comment: at the first glance, PRODUCT_BY_STORE Table is redundant - all information it contains can be found in PRODUCT_INV Table also. This means, you can read PRODUCT_INV Table only.

Comment: I have updated the PRODUCT_INV table as there are other columns as well.

Comment: I recommend using a [Materialized View](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCreateMV.html) to improve write performance and leave it to Cassandra to handle

Instead of making many multiple write queries.

In regards to getting the records, I suggest you invoke some business logic in the Cassandra cluster using [user defined aggregate functions](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCreateUDA.html) - this should be more performant than pulling massive amounts of raw data and processing it in the application's context

Comment: @ProblemSolver does PRODUCT_BY_STORE has other columns? Otherwise it is redundunt.

Comment: why can't you just read records from PRODUCT_INV  one by one? Each record there has Product_Code, StoreType and Storecode, so you can perform your business operation on that record, without retrieving any other information.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that **`PRODUCT_BY_STORE`** is redundant. Only **`PRODUCT_INV`** table is enough. Make `Product_Code` clustering key in **`PRODUCT_INV`** table. Example:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PRODUCT_INV (Product_Code TEXT,Storecode TEXT,StoreType TEXT,ProductInfo TEXT,INVENTORY DECIMAL, PRIMARY KEY (( Storecode, StoreType), Product_Code));
```

Now you can choose different **`Storecode` and `StoreType`** on the different thread and also could include `Product_Code` range query using limit. Note: choose an initial pivot and then update the pivot by last row's `Product_Code`.

```
Select * from PRODUCT_INV where Storecode = ? and StoreType = ? and Product_Code > <choosen_pivot/pagination> limit ?;
```

I guess this will give you `optimal performance` as you are doing a range query with limit. And different thread will use different node, as  `Storecode, StoreType` will be distributed in different nodes.